# how to hide side menu in login page angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to hide `side-menu` on my login page in `Angular2` application. Here is my app component which has top menu, side menu, and router-outlet.

#### app.component.html

```
<div class="row content-container">
    <top-menu></top-menu>
    <side-menu></side-menu>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As I could not figure out how to hide side-menu in login page currently I am hiding with `*ngIf` in side-menu.component.html like below ..

#### side-menu.component.html

```
<div class="side-menu sidebar-inverse" background-color="black" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
...
</div>
```

#### login.component.html

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
....
....
</div>
```

I tried with having whole html login.component.html like below ...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Login</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="app-container>
   ....
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

but the problem is once I login I have to refresh the browser to get the `side-menu` and once I logout I have to again refresh the browser to hide it. I don't like this approach as this is not the right way. I want to know correct way to hide side-menu in my `login`page. I am using `aungular-cli` and `Typescript` with `Aungular2`. Please suggest me how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to detect whether the user is logged in from the `app.component.ts`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to hide the side-menu on the login screen only? Then you can simply check the active `Route`. If you instead want to hide the side-menu when the user isn't logged in, you can go on with your `ngIf` and bind it to a `boolean` value loggedIn. This boolean then needs to change when user logs in/out.

Comment: place isLoggedIn variable in app.component.ts/
and <side-menu *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></side-menu>

Comment: @Springrbua Yes I want to hide the side-menu on the login screen only and thank you for thee hint on active `Route`. I am able to hide the side-menu with `router.events.subscribe((url:any) => {this.url = url.url; if (this.url.indexOf("/login") == 0) {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
          sessionStorage.clear();
          this.currentUser=null;
        }
        else {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
      }
    );`

@GabrieleB-David yes I was able to detect . 
@Thyagu thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to router events like this and have them automatically update check the isLogin variable. And you have to do this in the rootComponent or parent component that handles the displaying of the sidebar component. Heres some code to help you along:

```
//appComponent(root component)
<div class="wrapper">
<div *ngIf=isLoggedIn class="sidebar" data-background-color="white" data-active-color="danger">
    <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
</div>
<div class="main-panel">
    <navbar-cmp *ngIf=isLoggedIn></navbar-cmp>
    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <footer-cmp></footer-cmp>
</div>
```

And component should subscribe to router event like this:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { OnInit } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  showNav: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let urlSlice = e.url.toString().substr(0, 10);
        if (urlSlice.indexOf("login") !== -1) {
          console.log(urlSlice);
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.showNav = true;
    this.showSideBar = true;
  }
}
```